# How can add custom bytes to net.Conn struct or make one

Tags: go, tcp, proxy, reverse-proxy, tcpclient

I have some bytes which I want to add to a net.Conn or make a new net.Conn with those bytes. I have a func that proxy 2 conn and i want to insert custom data in that proxy.

```
var data = []byte("Hello")

// Create My Conn With Custom Data
conn := net.Conn{
            buff: data,
        }

// some func that want net.conn
func transport(src net.Conn, dst net.Conn) {
    defer dst.Close()
    defer src.Close()
    io.Copy(dst, src)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
func main() {
    // Create My Conn With Custom Data
    data := []byte("Hello")
    r1, w1 := io.Pipe()
    w1.Write(data)
    conn := &myConn{r1}

    // Connect to destination server
    dst, err := net.Dial("tcp", "example.com:80")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    // Proxy data from source to destination, including custom data
    transport(conn, dst)
}
```

myConn is a simple implementation of the net.Conn interface that wraps an io.Reader.

```
type myConn struct {
    r io.Reader
}
```

use it like so

```
func (c *myConn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return c.r.Read(b)
}

func (c *myConn) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    return 0, io.ErrClosedPipe
}

func (c *myConn) Close() error {
    return nil
}
```

Comment: what does myConn struct look like ?